# Is there RxJava(Rxandroid) equivalent of Handler.runWithScissors(final Runnable r, long timeout)?

Tags: android, rx-java2

Is there RxJava(Rxandroid)  equivalent of Handler.runWithScissors(final Runnable r, long timeout)?

I have a problem that getting the long-running result in `workerThread` asynchronously. (`mApplication.startApp()`)

At the same time, notify the progress in `uiThread`, my solution is below:

```java
/**
 * @return Observable<String> that subscribe the progress.
 */
public Observable<String> startApp() {
        Subject<String> mAppState = BehaviorSubject.create();

        Observable.just("Initialize...")
                .observeOn(mSchedulerProvider.single())
                .doOnNext((state) -> {
                    mAppState.onNext(state);
                    mApplication.startApp();
                })
                .doOnError((error) -> mAppState.onError(error))
                .map((state) -> "Initialization Complete.")
                .doOnNext((state) -> {
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(1000);
                    mAppState.onNext(state);
                    mAppState.onComplete();
                })
                .compose(bindToLifecycle())
                .subscribe();

        return mAppState.compose(bindToLifecycle())
                .observeOn(mSchedulerProvider.ui());
    }
```

Somebody has better solution? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need it?  RunWithScissors isn't even part of the public Android API-  you're peeking at functions that are supposed to be hidden and may be removed at any time with no warning and no backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that your solution is great below you have a simple solution 
when you do your job in computation or io and you update ui every 1 second

```
    Observable.just(1)
            .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .map(integer -> {
                // do your long job or computation
                return integer;
            })
            .skip(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .observeOn(AndroidScheduler.mainThread())
            .map(o -> {
                //UI update
                return o;
            }).subscribe();
```

Comment: I want to update ui twice.    once update ui before `do your long job or computation`.    once update ui after `do your long job or computation`

Comment: If `do your long job or computation` less than Thread.sleep(1000), above code will not trigger update ui.

Comment: @hanseyli if you want to update ui before doing long job you can do it in  onSubscribe. and yoes will not trigger but you have onComplete

Comment: @ Ricard thanks. But i must update ui many times now because the client prefer display the progress like 0%  10% 50% 75% 100%. /(ㄒoㄒ)/~~